# mapping and changing name of element in array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, vuejs2

i have an array like this and i want to change it . ı used map and for to reach an answer but i failed always

```
                {   type:"adults",   count: 2  },
                {   type:"children",   count: 3 },
                {  type:"infants", count: 3  }
            ]


    this.passengerSelectedCounts = this.passengerList.map(
                ({type,count}) => {
                    return  {???} ;
                } 
            );
```

i want to have result like this; i tried many ways but ı could not obtained exactly true answer for my problem

`{adults:2,children:3,infants:3}`

Comment: passengerList:[ {   type:"adults",   count: 2  },
                {   type:"children",   count: 3 },
                {  type:"infants", count: 3  }
            ]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  { type: "adults", count: 2 },
  { type: "children", count: 3 },
  { type: "infants", count: 3 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { type, count }) => {
  acc[type] = count;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can't use **map** because it will return a new array and you want the result as an object. You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as it will return a single output value.

Comment: thx for help and info . you gave so valuable information with description

Answer (score 0):

You could map the entries for a new object.

```js
const
    data = [{ type: "adults", count: 2 }, { type: "children", count: 3 }, { type: "infants", count: 3 }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ type, count }) => [type, count]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    type: "adults",
    count: 2
  },
  {
    type: "children",
    count: 3
  },
  {
    type: "infants",
    count: 3
  }
]
const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.type] = curr.count
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a.reduce((acum,{type,count}) => ({...acum,[type]:count}),{})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start doing it using basic for loops before diving into more advances techniques proposed by other members such as `array.reduce`, `Object.fromEntries` or object destructuring.

- classic for loop.

```
const passengerList = [
    {  type:"adults", count: 2  },
    {  type:"children", count: 3 },
    {  type:"infants", count: 3  }
];

const result = {};
let item;
for (let i = 0; i < passengerList.length; i++) {
    item = passengerList[i];
    result[item.type] = item.count;
}
console.log(result);
```

- new for...of loop.

```
const passengerList = [
    {  type:"adults", count: 2  },
    {  type:"children", count: 3 },
    {  type:"infants", count: 3  }
];

const result = {};
for (let item of passengerList){
    result[item.type] = item.count;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is also great approach nd it looks so clear thx